# How to hide a running program's window from batch

Tags: windows-10, batch-file, window

I am using a .bat file to start `RadeonSettings.exe`. However, after I run the program, I do not want that application's window open. How can I close the window but not terminate the program using a .bat file?

```
TIMEOUT 10 & REM
TASKKILL /F /IM RadeonSettings.exe
```

That does not work as it closes the application, not just the window.

Comment: You can't. That level of control is not possible with pure batch scripts. You would either need additional software or a more advanced language.

Comment: What does having this process up and running actually do that it does not do when it is not running? There are ways to make executable files run in a hidden fashion but first please let me know the answer to this question first.

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is say

```
exit
```

at the end of your batch file
(or, at the point in the logic
where you want to terminate the script and close the window). 
If you are running the batch file normally
from a normal Command Prompt window,
this will close the window.

Comment: did not work.  thankyou.

Comment: Apparently I misunderstood your question. You might get a better answer if you [edit your question](/posts/1251748/edit) to more clearly and completely explain  what you are doing.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the "Start" command?  It has options such as not closing until the program terminates, or the B switch - starting the app without creating a new window.

Drop to a command prompt and type "start /?"

Comment: I am already using this command:
start "" "C:\Program Files\Logitech Gaming Software\LCore.exe"